# Multiple symfony projects on same domain but different folders

Tags: php, apache, symfony1

Hi am building a several symfony pages on the same domain. Note that they must be on the same domain as different folders:
www.domain.com/[project1]/
www.domain.com/[project2]/
www.domain.com/[project3]/
www.domain.com/[project4]/

i would like the same symfony installation for these sites . Is this done easily? do i need symlinks to symfony in lib/vendor or use .htacess for each project?

i see an issue with the virtual host that must show the alias and directory for each project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track:

1. Replace lib/vendor/symfony with
   symlinks, if you really want to
   share the library
2. For each project, in httpd.conf
   `Alias projectN
   /path/to/projectN/web`

And you ought to be good to go.  No need for virtualhosts, since they're all running under the same domain.